# 'cd' complexity on ext4

Tags: performance, ext4, file-search, tree

In order to store attachments, a `/path/to/atts/` directory will have numerous child-directories (product IDs) created (from 1 to  ~10,000 or maybe more in the future), and in each of this subdir, 1 to ~10 attachment files will be created.

In `/path/to/atts/`

```
  1
  ├── file1.1
  ├── file1.2
  └── file1.3
  2
  └── file2.1
  ...
10000
  ├── file10000.1
  ├── file10000.2
  ├── file10000.3
  ├── file10000.4
  └── file10000.5
```

(actually 1 .. 10000 was chosen for the sake of a simpler explanation - IDs will be int32 numbers)

I'm wondering, on the ext4 file system, what is the `cd` (actually path resolution) complexity, when reaching `/path/to/atts/54321/...` for instance:

- Does the path resolution checks all inode / names one by one in the `atts` dir until `54321` is reached? Meaning on average n/2 inodes are checked (O(n))
- Or is there some tree structure within a dir that reduces the search (e.g. a trie tree, alphabetical order...), that would reduce dramatically the number of inodes checked, like log(n) instead of n/2?

If it is the former, I'll change the way the products tree structure is implemented.

*Just to be clear: the question is not about a `find` search of a file in a file system tree (that's O(n)). It's actually a path resolution (done by the FS), crossing a directory where thousands of file names reside (the product IDs)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about the hash tree index used for directories [here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Hash_Tree_Directories).

> A linear array of directory entries isn't great for performance, so a new feature was added to ext3 to provide a faster (but peculiar) balanced tree keyed off a hash of the directory entry name.